# Stored procedure has multiple SELECT statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This stored procedure has multiple `SELECT` statements - I need to write a condition based on one `SELECT` statement results among them without altering the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC Test
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS ID 
    FROM EMPLOYEE

    SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, STATE 
    FROM EMPLOYEE --NEED TO TAKE ROW COUNT 
END
```

After executing the stored procedure, I'll get 2 result sets. But I need to row count of 2nd select statement, without altering the stored procedure.

Based on that rowcount, I need to work further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exec Test 
select @@rowcount
```

In this case, @@rowcount will always return last result set row count.